# Is there an alternate way to do the same without for loop?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays `A` and `l`. The dimension of `A` is `(n, x, y)` and the dimension of `l` is `(n,1)`. I get the result as follows:

```
res = []
for i in range(n):
    res.append(A[i, x, l[i])
```

This way of getting the result is very time consuming for a larger value of `n`. Is there an alternative to get the same result quickly?

Comment: `x` is ambiguous in your code. But assuming it's a single value `x0`, `A[range(n), x0, l]` might be it. But `l` should be a 1d array with shape `(n,)`.

Comment: `l[i]` is guaranteed to be with `0<l[i]<y` for all values of `i`?

Comment: `x` could be any fixed number. Yes the elements in the array `l` are guaranteed to be valid indices when operated on `A`.

Comment: You can always easily write a *while* loop instead...

Comment: To be clear, I don't want to use any loops. I was looking for some standard numpy functions that could be faster than loops.

Comment: You could just write `[)`, that gives you the same syntax error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `0<=l[i]<y` for all values of `i`:

```
>>> n,x,y = 4,5,6
>>> A = np.random.randint(0,10,(n,x,y))
array([[[3, 3, 3, 8, 7, 0],
        [8, 1, 1, 5, 3, 8],
        [0, 1, 0, 4, 1, 3],
        [2, 2, 1, 8, 6, 5],
        [2, 5, 9, 2, 6, 3]],

       [[9, 7, 4, 6, 7, 7],
        [1, 7, 0, 4, 9, 6],
        [8, 0, 8, 6, 7, 8],
        [1, 9, 7, 8, 7, 6],
        [2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 8]],

       [[2, 8, 5, 7, 9, 4],
        [7, 2, 2, 5, 2, 1],
        [0, 8, 6, 4, 1, 2],
        [6, 9, 9, 0, 2, 4],
        [9, 9, 1, 6, 7, 0]],

       [[3, 8, 4, 3, 5, 6],
        [5, 3, 7, 7, 4, 6],
        [9, 0, 7, 9, 2, 1],
        [1, 6, 2, 2, 9, 5],
        [5, 0, 9, 0, 5, 2]]])
>>> l = np.random.randint(low=0, high=y-1, size=(n,1))
array([[0],
       [1],
       [3],
       [1]])
>>> x0 = 2
>>> res = []
>>> for i in range(n):
        res.append(A[i, x0, l[i])

>>> res
[array([0]), array([0]), array([4]), array([0])]
```

`numpy`:

```
>>> A[range(n), 2, l.flatten()]
array([0, 0, 4, 0])
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

what about list comprehension?

```
res=[A[i, x, l[i] for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: This still uses loop. I am looking for something that uses standard functions in numpy.